# Foreign key for same table in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a data model that has a folder structure defined through the data. Various objects can be in these folders, including folders themselves, similarly to how folders in Explorer cascade and can contain each other.

I think I've figured out how foreign keys work in this stack, but when I go to migrate it to the database, the system won't let me. What's the issue? There's got to be a way to nest these folder entries inside each other, right?

```
namespace api.Models
{
    public class Folder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int SuperFolderId { get; set; }
        public Folder SuperFolder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oversight here is that self-referencing foreign keys can't be nullable. Imagine a file structure where EVERY folder needs a superfolder. It would either go up forever, or two folders would have to reference each other and it would loop.

It's the same as the classic self-referencing key example of Employees having Managers, where Managers are also on the Employee table. You can only go so far up the chain before you reach the head of the company.

The system assumes foreign keys are not nullable, and so it makes them required without the need of the [Required] attribute. It is sometimes valid to make a foreign key optional, and to do that, you turn the int into a nullable int, or "int?". The code below fixes the problem.

```
namespace api.Models
{
    public class Folder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? SuperFolderId { get; set; }
        public Folder SuperFolder { get; set; }
    }
}
```